# STM32 cube programmer can read but not write

Tags: stm32, microcontroller

I recently soldered together a PCB with an STM32F103CBT6.

I have header pins connected to the SWCLK, SWDIO, 3V3 and GND of the MCU.

I realize now I didn't connect NRST to anything (floating), but reading around, it sounds like it has an internal pull-up resistor connected to VDD.  Boot0 and Boot1 are connected to ground.

I connect to the MCU with an ST-LINK/V2 ISOL and STM32CubeProgrammer (this is how I connect to a Blue Pill, which I can program fine.  And this method doesn't require Boot to be set HIGH or an NRST connection).

STM32CubeProgrammer is able to connect to the STM32F103CBT6, and it seems to read from flash memory okay (all bytes are 0xFFFFFFFF).  In the Erasing & Programming tab, Start Programming doesn't result in any errors unless I check "Verify Programming", in which case it fails with the following error.

```
  23:50:20 : Error: Data mismatch found at address  0x08000000 (byte = 0xFF instead of 0x00)
  23:50:20 : Error: Download verification failed
```

Under the Option Bytes tab, RDP is unchecked.  All "Write Protection" fields are checked.  If I try to edit any of the option bytes, it fails with something like the following error:

```
Error: Option Byte Programming failed.
Erorr: Expected value for Option Byte "nRST_STDBY": 0x0, found 0x1
```

Under the MCU core tab, the Core State is "Halted".  If I try to reset/run the MCU, it goes in to "LOCKUP".

I read that new chips need to be unlocked?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Doh.  I didn't connect any of the MCU VSS pins to Ground...

I'm guessing that would cause some issues.

Comment: I was able to connect a small jumper wire to the VSSA pin and ground.  Then the programming succeeded and the program runs.